# R jsonlite: create JSON data in a specific format

Tags: json, r, jsonlite

I want to create JSON data using R's jsonlite package to load to [DynamoDB](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/gettingstartedguide/Welcome.html) using [Python](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/gettingstartedguide/GettingStarted.Python.html). I want the data to be in the structure shown below.  How can I create this in R? I tried creating a data frame where one of the columns is a list and change the data frame to json but the result is not in the required format. I also tried a converting a list which contains a list, but the structure of the output json is not what I want.

```
[
{
    "ID": 100,
    "title": "aa",
    "more": {
      "interesting":"yes",
      "new":"no",
      "original":"yes"
    }
},

{
    "ID": 110,
    "title": "bb",
    "more": {
      "interesting":"no",
      "new":"yes",
      "original":"yes"
    }
},

{
    "ID": 200,
    "title": "cc",
    "more": {
      "interesting":"yes",
      "new":"yes",
      "original":"no"
    }
  }
]
```

Here is my sample data and what I tried:

```
library(jsonlite)

ID=c(100,110,200)
Title=c("aa","bb","cc")
more=I(list(Interesting=c("yes","no","yes"),new=c("no","yes","yes"),original=c("yes","yes","no")))

 a=list(ID=ID,Title=Title,more=more)
 a=toJSON(a)
 write(a,"temp.json")  # this does not give the structure I want
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

this will produce what you need:

```
library(jsonlite)

ID=c(100,110,200)
Title=c("aa","bb","cc")

df <- data.frame(ID, Title)
more=data.frame(Interesting=c("yes","no","yes"),new=c("no","yes","yes"),original=c("yes","yes","no"))
df$more <- more

toJSON(df)
```

output:

```
[{
        "ID": 100,
        "Title": "aa",
        "more": {
            "Interesting": "yes",
            "new": "no",
            "original": "yes"
        }
    }, {
        "ID": 110,
        "Title": "bb",
        "more": {
            "Interesting": "no",
            "new": "yes",
            "original": "yes"
        }
    }, {
        "ID": 200,
        "Title": "cc",
        "more": {
            "Interesting": "yes",
            "new": "yes",
            "original": "no"
        }
    }
]
```

Comment: pasting and running your code in my Rstudio produces the folllowing:

> toJSON(df)
[1] "{\"ID\":[100,110,200],\"Title\":[\"aa\",\"bb\",\"cc\"],\"more\":{\"Interesting\":[\"yes\",\"no\",\"yes\"],\"new\":[\"no\",\"yes\",\"yes\"],\"original\":[\"yes\",\"yes\",\"no\"]}}

why?